# Comparing cells in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Let strCellArr be a 4000*1 array of cells. Each cell is a string.

What is the fastest way to tell if every cell has a string of length 100.

In other words, I want something that does the same thing as

```
a= true;
For (i =0; i =length(strCellArr); i++)
    if length(strCellArr{i}) ~= 100
         a = false;
    end
end
```

A related question:

I can convert the array to a 4000*100 array of characters with

```
charArr = char(strCellArr);
```

However, this will introduce whitespaces in lines that do not have 100 characters. So if line 34 only has 30 characters. Then

```
charArr(34)(50)
```

will return a whitespace.

How do I check that every single character is only certain characters, in my case (A, T, C, or G). Is there a way to do it without using a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ooooh I just love questions that start like "what is the fastest way to do ..."

Here's a few alternatives, and a comparison:

```
% Initalize

map = 'CATG';     
strCellArr = cellfun(@(x) map(randi(4,100,1)),cell(4000,1), 'UniformOutput', false);


% Your original method 
tic
a = true;
for el = strCellArr
    if length(el{1}) ~= 100
         a = false;
         break;
    end
end
toc

% My solution 
tic
a = all(cellfun('length', strCellArr) == 100);
toc

% Dang Khoa's method
tic
a = all( cellfun(@(x) length(x) == 100, strCellArr) );
toc

% Engineero's method
tic
a = all(cellfun(@length, strCellArr) == 100);
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.001158 seconds. % loop
Elapsed time is 0.000455 seconds. % cellfun; string argument
Elapsed time is 0.031897 seconds. % cellfun; anonymous function
Elapsed time is 0.006994 seconds. % cellfun; function handle
```

Little known fact: the string inputs to `cellfun` refer to functions built directly into the `cellfun` binary, and therefore do not require the evaluation of an anonymous function. In other words, `cellfun` does not have to make a pass through the MATLAB interpreter on every of its iterations, making this *raging* fast :)

Now, the second part of your question:

```
% Engineero
tic
A = 'ATCG';
all(all(ismember(char(strCellArr), A)));
toc

% My solution 
tic
C = char(strCellArr);
~any(C(:)==' ');
toc
```

Results:

```
Elapsed time is 0.061168 seconds. % ismember
Elapsed time is 0.005098 seconds. % direct comparison to whitespace
```

This difference arises because `ismember` is implemented in MATLAB m-code, and is riddled with code intended for user-friendliness (error checks, errors, warnings, etc.), elaborate generalizations, loop structures, and many other things that are all together a performance penalty.

Since we know beforehand that *only* spaces will be added to the array upon casting it to `char`, we do *not* have to explicitly check for occurrences of `'A'`, `'C'`, `'T'`, `'G'`, but only for their *abscence*. Meaning, just look for those spaces :)

Needless to say, these times are *all* virtually negligible, and this is all more mental masturbation than actually really useful. But its fun! :)

Comment: That's intriguing that using the `== 100` inside the `cellfun` as in my solution increased runtime by 455% compared to putting it outside! I wonder why this is. Obviously in this case it's negligible, but scaling the problem up would be inefficient. I think my solution is better from a *programmer's* prospective, i.e., the "design intent" is more clear than @Engineero's solution. But obviously he wins on speed. Also, thanks for the learning you've given me re:string argument! I still prefer using anon fcns, again because design intent is clear. But this is good if speed is needed.

Comment: @DangKhoa: I agree. That's actually pretty often the case in MATLAB; the more sugar-coated something is, the more the performance penalty will be. I *think* the difference comes from the fact that the `@(x)` forces *evaluation* in the MATLAB interpreter, while the direct `@length` allows for only a *lookup* of the `length` function.

Comment: +1 Nitpick: the `@length` isn't an anonymous function at all; it's a function handle, to the (probably builtin) `length` function. So "shorter anonymous function" is a bit of a misnomer. That said, anons are a bit slower (at least in the past). But the longer anonymous function is also just doing more (expensive) work, with extra function calls (`==` and the anon call itself, on top of `length()`) and building the `100` and temporaries.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, you could use `all(cellfun(@length, strCellArr) == 100)`, which will return a 1 for "true" if every element in the cell has a length of 100 elements.

For your second question, you may be able to use `all(ismember(charArr, A))` where `A = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']`. See the documentation on [all](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question: this sounds like a job for [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). `cellfun` lets you operate on each cell in a cell array. (As an aside, `arrayfun` lets you do the same but on a regular array). (Note that your original code is not MATLAB syntax, particularly the `for` loop.)

So you could do something like

```
res = cellfun(@(x) length(x) == 100, strCellArr);
```

Here, `res` will be a `logical` since the `==` condition will evaluate to 0 or 1. Then, you can see if `all` of the results are 1, i.e., all the strings in `strCellArr` are of length 100:

```
a = all(res);
if a == 0
    disp('One or more strings does not have 100 characters!');
else
    disp('All strings have 100 characters!');
end
```